# Unbounded symmetric probability density function with finite $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |z|^3 f(z) dz$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f^2(z)dz$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, statistics, functions

## Condition

1. $f(z)$ is a probability density function (p.d.f.)
2. $f(z) = f(-z)$
3. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f^2(z)dz < \infty$
4. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty z^2 f(z)dz < \infty$
5. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |z|^3 f(z) dz < \infty$
6. $f$ is unbounded

## My idea

$$
f(z)=\frac{|z|^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{4}\mathbb I_{[-1, 1]\backslash\{0\}}
$$

This unfortunately does not meet the third condition.

And Gaussian does not meet the sixth condition.

**Is there any function f that satisfies 1~6?**

Comment: Maybe you can try to change a bit the gaussian distribution so that it verifies the sixth condition, e.g. imposing that $f$ is the identity on $\mathbb N^*$ and $f(-n) = f(n)$ (I didn't really think about it) ?

Comment: The gaussian looks good. If you had a gaussian and added point masses at every integer g(z) = z , it would be unbounded and the extra masses wouldn't change the integral. You would have a non continuous density function

Comment: I just provided an answer. I am wondering why you are looking for such a density.

Comment: Note that the fifth condition implies the forth.

Comment: $Ce^{-\vert x\vert}\vert x\vert^{-1/3}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea was good, to have $L^2$ integrability, just replace $1/2$ by a smaller exponent, such as $1/4$, that is
$$
f(z) = \frac{3}{8\,|z|^{1/4}} \,\mathbf{1}_{[-1,1]\setminus\{0\}}(z).
$$

Answer (score 1):

For $-1 < \alpha=\beta < 0$, I define the following pdf for any $x$:

$$f(x)=Ce^{\alpha|x|}\left(1-e^{-|x|} \right)^{\beta}$$

**Please let me know if you have seen such a distribution before.**

I set $\alpha=\beta=-0.3$ to meet the second condition (for $-1 <\alpha=\beta \le -0.5$ the second is violated).

I used [this website](https://www.integral-calculator.com/) for numerical integration.

$1 \over C $ is about $\small 7.766444154901865$; the accuracy is $\small1.358912982141192 10^{-13}.$ Hence, the **first** holds.

It is also a symmetric function, so the **second** is satisficed.

The integral in the **third** condition is about $\small C\times 6.606531998377108$; the accuracy is $\small 2.566480361565482 10^{-11}$

The integral in the **fifth** condition is about $\small C\times 1482.848241998203 $; the accuracy is $\small 1.235435060923171 10^{-8}$. Hence, the **forth** is also implied.

As $\beta=-0.3<0$, the density is also an unbounded function and the **sixth** holds (see [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/e2tbbig0x2) for a demo of the pdf).

For $\alpha=\beta=-0.5$, the indefinite integral of the density has a simple formula: $$\dfrac{2x\arctan\left(\sqrt{1-\mathrm{e}^{-\left|x\right|}}\,\mathrm{e}^\frac{\left|x\right|}{2}\right)}{\left|x\right|}.$$

However, for $\alpha=-0.3$, the indefinite integral is very complex:

$$ \small \small \small \dfrac{x\cdot\left(\frac{5{\cdot}2^\frac{3}{2}\ln\left(\left|\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+5}\,\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\left|x\right|}{10}}}{\sqrt[10]{1-\mathrm{e}^{-\left|x\right|}}}-\frac{\sqrt{2}\,\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\left|x\right|}{5}}}{\sqrt[5]{1-\mathrm{e}^{-\left|x\right|}}}-\sqrt{2}\right|\right)-5{\cdot}2^\frac{3}{2}\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+5}\,\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\left|x\right|}{10}}}{\sqrt[10]{1-\mathrm{e}^{-\left|x\right|}}}+\frac{\sqrt{2}\,\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\left|x\right|}{5}}}{\sqrt[5]{1-\mathrm{e}^{-\left|x\right|}}}+\sqrt{2}\right)}{2\sqrt{16{\cdot}5^\frac{3}{2}+200}-2\left(5-\sqrt{5}\right)\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+5}}+\frac{5{\cdot}2^\frac{3}{2}\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{5-\sqrt{5}}\,\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\left|x\right|}{10}}}{\sqrt[10]{1-\mathrm{e}^{-\left|x\right|}}}+\frac{\sqrt{2}\,\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\left|x\right|}{5}}}{\sqrt[5]{1-\mathrm{e}^{-\left|x\right|}}}+\sqrt{2}\right)-5{\cdot}2^\frac{3}{2}\ln\left(\left|\frac{\sqrt{5-\sqrt{5}}\,\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\left|x\right|}{10}}}{\sqrt[10]{1-\mathrm{e}^{-\left|x\right|}}}-\frac{\sqrt{2}\,\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\left|x\right|}{5}}}{\sqrt[5]{1-\mathrm{e}^{-\left|x\right|}}}-\sqrt{2}\right|\right)}{2\sqrt{5-\sqrt{5}}\left(\sqrt{5}+5\right)-2\sqrt{200-16{\cdot}5^\frac{3}{2}}}+\frac{2^\frac{11}{4}\left(\frac{5\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+5}}{2^\frac{3}{2}}-\sqrt{2{\cdot}5^\frac{3}{2}+25}\right)\arctan\left(\frac{\frac{2^\frac{3}{2}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\left|x\right|}{10}}}{\sqrt[10]{1-\mathrm{e}^{-\left|x\right|}}}-\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+5}}{2^\frac{5}{4}\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-\frac{\sqrt{5}+5}{2^\frac{5}{2}}}}\right)-2^\frac{11}{4}\left(\sqrt{2{\cdot}5^\frac{3}{2}+25}-\frac{5\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+5}}{2^\frac{3}{2}}\right)\arctan\left(\frac{\frac{2^\frac{3}{2}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\left|x\right|}{10}}}{\sqrt[10]{1-\mathrm{e}^{-\left|x\right|}}}+\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+5}}{2^\frac{5}{4}\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-\frac{\sqrt{5}+5}{2^\frac{5}{2}}}}\right)}{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-\frac{\sqrt{5}+5}{2^\frac{5}{2}}}\left(2\sqrt{16{\cdot}5^\frac{3}{2}+200}-2\left(5-\sqrt{5}\right)\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+5}\right)}+\frac{2^\frac{11}{4}\left(\sqrt{25-2{\cdot}5^\frac{3}{2}}-\frac{5\sqrt{5-\sqrt{5}}}{2^\frac{3}{2}}\right)\arctan\left(\frac{\frac{2^\frac{3}{2}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\left|x\right|}{10}}}{\sqrt[10]{1-\mathrm{e}^{-\left|x\right|}}}+\sqrt{5-\sqrt{5}}}{2^\frac{5}{4}\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{5}-5}{2^\frac{5}{2}}+\sqrt{2}}}\right)-2^\frac{11}{4}\left(\frac{5\sqrt{5-\sqrt{5}}}{2^\frac{3}{2}}-\sqrt{25-2{\cdot}5^\frac{3}{2}}\right)\arctan\left(\frac{\frac{2^\frac{3}{2}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\left|x\right|}{10}}}{\sqrt[10]{1-\mathrm{e}^{-\left|x\right|}}}-\sqrt{5-\sqrt{5}}}{2^\frac{5}{4}\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{5}-5}{2^\frac{5}{2}}+\sqrt{2}}}\right)}{\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{5}-5}{2^\frac{5}{2}}+\sqrt{2}}\left(2\sqrt{5-\sqrt{5}}\left(\sqrt{5}+5\right)-2\sqrt{200-16{\cdot}5^\frac{3}{2}}\right)}+2\arctan\left(\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\left|x\right|}{10}}}{\sqrt[10]{1-\mathrm{e}^{-\left|x\right|}}}\right)\right)}{\left|x\right|} $$